# JQuery Checking the Length

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text field (datepicker) and if someone pick a date, the button will change to another color.  But somehow, it doesn't work out.  Please give me a hand.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"> 
<button type="button" onclick="" class="buttDis">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var txtCheck = $('#datepicker').val();
            if ( txtCheck.length > 0)
                {
                    $('button').addClass('buttEna');
                }
    }



  );
```

CSS

```
.buttDis {background-color: gray;}
.buttEna{background-color:blue}
```

Comment: Your code is not linking any event to the textbox. It only wait to the document ready event to check if the text is changed. But at that time the user didn't do anything, ,, what you need to do is bind an event of that textbox to check if the txt is changed, , see tymejv answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `change` event to fire each time the `input` changes:

```
$('#datepicker').change(function() {
    var txtCheck = this.value;
    if ( txtCheck.length > 0) {
        $('button').addClass('buttEna');
    }
});
```